# Unable to instantiate XrplClient object (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, xrp

I'm just getting started with XRPL4J, and have an issue:

```
HttpUrl rippledUrl = HttpUrl.get("https://s.altnet.rippletest.net:51234/");

XrplClient xrplClient = new XrplClient(rippledUrl);
```

I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field IMPL_LOOKUP in class Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup; (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
```

Any pointers would be useful - I'm using v2.0.0 of the libraries.

Sorry for the noobish question - just wasn't able to find much useful by searching.

Comment: On doing some more digging, this seems to be related to XrplClient->OKHtttp3->OpenFeign->feign-jackson, and it not being able to find the IMPL_LOOKUP field in the android 10 JRE. I tried a couple of workarounds but no joy. Seems like a problem with that implementation not accounting for differences in JRE's rather than with XRPL4J directly.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Was an Android incompatibility in feign-core / DefaultMethodHandler.java

PR submitted.

My fork: https://github.com/xrpdevs/feign

HTH some Android developers out there!